# How can i do conditional style in MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I wanna make dynamic style in an MVC project. For instance, a have view like this[image: like this]

```
<div class="bg-purple text-center text-white pb5">
    <div data-bind="visible:ShowMesaage()===1">
        <strong>@common.welcome</strong>
        <p>
            <span data-bind="text:TempDate"></span>@common.reservationMessage
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'm getting some information from the api(test1 and test2). If test1 comes, I want the div's background to change and p's and strong's font to change, likewise, if test2 comes, I want another color and another font.

how can i do it? I don't want to change the controller if possible

[image]

```
<div class="bg-purple text-center text-white pb5">
    <div data-bind="visible:ShowMesaage()===1">
        <strong class="@(apiInfo='test1' ? "tyest1" : "test2")">@common.welcome</strong>
        <p>
            <span data-bind="text:TempDate"></span>@common.reservationMessage
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

i did like this but I think doing this for all tags would take a long time and would not be efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
<strong Class="@(apiInfo == 'test1' ? 'test1':'test2')">@common.welcome</strong>
```

OR

```
<strong Class='@(apiInfo == "test1" ? "test1":"test2")'>@common.welcome</strong>
```

**Just check the double Quote and single Quote placement and there you go.**

**If you want other approach then this,**

```
  <div class="bg-purple text-center text-white pb5">
        <div data-bind="visible:ShowMesaage()===1">
            <strong class="@apiInfo">@common.welcome</strong>
            <p>
                <span data-bind="text:TempDate"></span>@common.reservationMessage
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the style that you can use direct your ApiInfo as class that would be so good approach,

```
   <style>
        .test1 
        {
           background-color:#fff; //[your style]
        }
        
        .test2
        {
           background-color:red; //[your style]
        }
   </style>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. As i said this method take a long time because maybe the code contains 100 tags Is there a more logical solution?

Comment: For that would you please explain the whole feature what you are trying to achieve in here by looking at picture its quite difficult to think that there might be a foreach or what would be the whole html looks like. then I would happy to answer with different approach.

Comment: Updated the answer please check if that can help.